# "by both parties" vs "by the both parties" vs "by both the parties"

Tags: grammar

I have encountered all three options in various texts:

- by both parties
- by the both parties
- by both the parties

Are they all correct? What is the rule?

Example sentence:

> It needs to be agreed by both parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"by both parties" - correct.

"by both the parties" - correct.

"by both of the parties" - correct.

"by the both parties" - wrong.

You can never have "the both" directly followed by a noun or adjective, nor on its own. "The both parties" would never be correct.

Colloquially you sometimes find "the both of" followed by a pronoun. ("The both of us" means the same thing as "both of us" - although the former is restricted to informal use. "Both of us" is preferred.)

Comment: Thank you! But why to use "the" in "by both the parties"? Doesn't both already work as a specificator?

Comment: The "the" in "both the parties" is optional. "Both parties" and "both the parties" mean the same thing.

Comment: I think if anything "both parties" may be preferable. There are some cases where "both the" sounds awkward.